# How can I get shader node values based on object angle?

Tags: animation, node-editor, light

I'm trying to **automatically** change a blackbody's value based on a sunlamp's directional angle.

When the sunlamp shines horizontal, I would like to have a minimum value represented in the shader editor *(minimum value = user defined)*.
When at it's utmost vertical position, I would like to get a maximum value (maximum value = user defined).

I've tried out a couple of things:

- Manually adding keyframes *(this breakes the correct values when the sun's path deviates from eg. different seasons.)*
- Adding drivers *(also breakes the correct values over time, and I don't have a lot of experience with drivers and their possibilities)*
- Using the sun's greatest height in additon of a constrained parented object to determine a min. and max. value (this also deviates when using different times of the year. I felt like I was really overthinking this one)*

[image: Sun's rotational position]

Note:

- If possible I'd like to get an additional proposal for adding some sort of fallof to the values so their values don't change in a linear way as much:
  [image: curvature falloff]
- Is it possible to get these values in both object and world shader nodes?

Comment: That can be similar to this (replace the camera by the lamp): https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/147730/19156